# Select 2 types of rows from dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

[image]

I want to select rows in the data frame with `New state == 'Granted' | 'Pending promotion'`

How can I do this in python?

I know it may be simple but not able to find anything online!
Here's what I tried.

```
data=data.loc[(data['New state']=='Pending Promotion') & (data['New state']=='Granted')]
```

But gives an empty dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
data = data[data["New state"].isin(["Pending Promotion","Granted"])]
```